# Discord.js "undefined" before first array object in embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot command where you can build a city. There is a list command I am trying to make which lists all of the roads and places made in the city. Both of them keep having "undefined" before the first line in the value place. Here is what I get in my embed: [the places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A759Z.png), [the roads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I73ey.png)

Here is my code for both of the commands:

```
const citydb = require("city.json")
client.on("message", message => {
    let { localroad, routeroad, privateplace, publicplace } = ``;

    for (var i = 0; i < citydb["roads-local"].length; i++) {localroad += citydb["roads-local"][i]}
    for (var i = 0; i < citydb["roads-route"].length; i++) {routeroad += citydb["roads-route"][i]}
    for (var i = 0; i < citydb["places-private"].length; i++) {privateplace += citydb["places-private"][i]}
    for (var i = 0; i < citydb["places-public"].length; i++) {publicplace += citydb["places-public"][i]}

    if (message.content === config.pfx+"city-listroads") {
        let roadlist = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Moth City Roads Registry")
            .setDescription("A list of roads created in Moth City.")
            .setColor("#2C3E50")
            .addFields(
                { name: "Local Roads", value: localroad, inline: true },
                { name: "Routes", value: routeroad, inline: true }
            )
        message.channel.send(roadlist)
    } else if (message.content === config.pfx+"city-listplaces") {
        let placelist = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Moth City Places Registry")
            .setDescription("A list of places created in Moth City.")
            .setColor("#2C3E50")
            .addFields(
                { name: "Homes", value: privateplace, inline: false },
                { name: "Places", value: publicplace, inline: false }
            )
        message.channel.send(placelist)
    }
});
```

And here is my data in the JSON file:

```
{"roads-route": ["MR 1 \n","MR 40 \n","MR 66 \n","MR 166 \n","MR 29 \n"],"roads-local":["Mist Parkway \n","Swagith Highway \n","Lepid Avenue \n","Wings Street \n","N Indigo Highway\n","S Indigo Highway\n"],"places-private":["7253 Lepid Avenue - Zak's House \n","9446 Mist Parkway - Sqmapi's House \n"],"places-public":["6030 Wings Street - Mountain Top Cake Shop \n"]}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is trying to use destructuring to set all these variables, but none of their names is a key of ``` `` ```:

```js
let { localroad, routeroad, privateplace, publicplace } = ``;
```

If you want to set several variables to the same initial value, the syntax is different:

```js
let localroad, routeroad, privateplace, publicplace
localroad = routeroad = privateplace = publicplace = ""
```

There is a simpler way of joining the data together, though:

```js
let localroad = citydb["roads-local"].join("")
let routeroad = citydb["roads-route"].join("")
let privateplace = citydb["places-private"].join("")
let publicplace = citydb["places-public"].join("")
```

Going beyond that, if you change `join("")` to `join("\n")` in each of those cases, you can leave out the `\n` at the end of each entry in your JSON files.